# How to change this following CURL to REST Client in JAVA?

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient

My Curl Command is,

curl -X POST "https://myTestServer/knox/api/v1/files" -H "accept: application/json" -H
"authorization: Basic YTM1MjM0ODpQYXNzd29yZEAzNDU=" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F
"file=@test.pdf;type=application/pdf" -F "entity={"name": "PDF.22427922.02", "size":
160135,"organization": "TEST" }"

Code is

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.TrustSelfSignedStrategy;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
import org.apache.http.entity.FileEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContextBuilder;

public class Main_test {
    public static void main(String Args[]) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException {
      
        whenSendMultipartRequestUsingHttpClient_thenCorrect();
    }
    
    public static void whenSendMultipartRequestUsingHttpClient_thenCorrect() 
            throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, KeyManagementException {
        
        
                SSLContextBuilder builder = new SSLContextBuilder();
                builder.loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy());
                SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
                        builder.build());
                CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(
                        sslsf).build();
        
        
        
               HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://myTestServer/knox/api/v1/files");
               httppost.addHeader("accept","application/json");
               httppost.addHeader("authorization","Basic YTM1MjM0ODpQYXNzd29yZEAzNDU=");
               httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data");

               HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
                       .setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE)
                       .addBinaryBody("file", new File("C:\\users\\6576788\\JLink_Apps\\test.pdf"), ContentType.create("application/pdf"), "test.pdf")
                       .addTextBody("entity", "'name': 'PDF.20890607.02', 'size': 160135, 'organization': 'TEST'}").build();
               

              httppost.setEntity(entity);
              

              CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httppost);
              
              BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
               String response1 = reader.readLine();
               System.out.println("response:"+response1);
            System.out.println("response:"+response.toString());
              client.close();
          }

}

````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Throws
response:{"message":"Cannot retrieve part of request","errorCode":"BAD_REQUEST"}
response:HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request [Date: Mon, 21 Sep 2020 10:35:15 GMT, Expires: 0, Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate, X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block, Pragma: no-cache, X-Frame-Options: DENY, Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains, X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff, Content-Type: application/json, Content-Length: 71, Connection: close] ResponseEntityProxy{[Content-Type: application/json,Content-Length: 71,Chunked: false]}}
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````